# Hide date field on taxonomy page

Tags: taxonomy-terms

How do I hide this date field on this page? The page is a taxonomy term, not a node.

[image]

Under Manage Display, I've set Taxonomy Post Date to "Visually Hidden" but it persists.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only hid the field *label*. To hide the field entirely, drag the field to the "disabled" section.

Comment: Brilliant, that worked. Thanks for helping a noob!

Comment: Please accept the answer.